# SVNkit cannot create SVNRepoitory

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am trying to run a diff on two svn urls using SVNkit.  The problem is that I get the error when `diff.doDiff` is called.

> org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Unable to create
>   SVNRepository object for
>   'http://svn.codehaus.org/jruby/trunk/jruby/src/org/jruby/Finalizable.java'
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:55)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:40)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.io.SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNRepositoryFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.DefaultSVNRepositoryPool.createRepository(DefaultSVNRepositoryPool.java:213)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNClientManager.createRepository(SVNClientManager.java:242)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.createRepository(SVNBasicClient.java:231)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNDiffClient.doDiffURLURL(SVNDiffClient.java:769)
>     at
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNDiffClient.doDiff(SVNDiffClient.java:310)
>     at SVNTest.main(SVNTest.java:30)

I have double checked the URLs (I can open them in TortoiseSVN client).  Can anybody help me know what is going on?  I have posted the code I am running below.

```
SVNClientManager manager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(false), user, pass);

SVNDiffClient diff = manager.getDiffClient();
    //ISVNDiffStatusHandler diffStatus = new ISVNDiffStatusHandler();

try {
SVNURL oldURL = SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url);    
diff.doDiff(SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url), SVNRevision.create(oldVersion), SVNURL.parseURIDecoded(url), SVNRevision.HEAD, false, false, System.out);
} catch (SVNException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

have you called the following static method?

> DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();

This needs to be called before accessing any `http://` repositories and the similar

> SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();

should be used for `svn://` repositories.